# Como copiar textos do e-mail atual no Outlook para células no Excel usando VBA?

Tags: excel-vba, outlook

Boa tarde a todos. Eu quero criar uma macro no Excel que copie dados específicos de um e-mail selecionado no Outlook, colando os mesmos em colunas respectivas de uma planilha, criando uma base de dados. Reforçando que preciso copiar de um único e-mail que estiver selecionado para que possa trabalhar nele individualmente, não quero percorrer todos os que estão na pasta de uma vez.

As imagens abaixo servem de exemplo para o funcionamento da macro. Os dados correspondentes do e-mail que estiver selecionado são gravados em suas respectivas colunas. Segue um código que trabalhei abaixo, porém não fui muito longe, já que não sei definir o objeto do e-mail atualmente selecionado, mas deixei alguns comentários que orientam sobre todo o procedimento. Essa macro me quebraria um galho enorme, podem me ajudar?

[image: Exemplo de um E-mail atual com as informações visadas]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: A planilha é gradualmente preenchida com os dados correspondentes dos e-mails]

```
Sub dados_eMail()

Dim outApp As Outlook.Application
Dim outMapi As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim outMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim outHTML As MSHTML.HTMLDocument

Dim WB As Workbook
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim Mail As String
Dim inbox As String
Dim lastrow As Long

Set WB = Workbooks("Book1")
Set WS = Sheets("Sheet1")
WB.Activate
WS.Activate
lastrow = WS.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Mail = "some_mail_user@outlook.com"
inbox = "Inbox"

Set outMapi = outApp.GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders(pasta).Folders(subpasta)
Set outHTML = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

'1) outMail recebe o objeto que representa o e-mail atualmente selecionado no Outlook;
'2) As palavras que representam os títulos dos cabeçalhos são procurados no e-mail, e os textos abaixo delas são copiados para a primeira célula vazia de cada coluna;
'3) Com todas as células de uma linha preenchidas, a macro é encerrada. 

 End Sub
```